# object not set to instance of an object error while creating a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have alist that needs to get populated on page load the following is the code in dal

```
      public List<KeyValuePair<Guid, string>> GetProjectName()
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<Guid, string>> List = null;
        try
        {
            using (LiveLeaseEntities db = LiveLeaseHelper.GetDbLiveLeaseEntities())
            {
                var projects = (from p in db.t_Project
                                where p.IsActive == true
                                select p).ToList();
                if (projects != null)
                {
                    foreach (t_Project p in projects)
                    {
                        List.Add(new KeyValuePair<Guid, string>(p.ProjectId, p.ProjectName));
                    }
                }

                return List;
```

i get object not set to instance of object error. steping through projects show a count of 7 but i get error.

Comment: `ToList` never returns `null` but an empty list, so where do you get the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set your List as `null` by this line

```
List<KeyValuePair<Guid, string>> List = null;
```

and then trying to add item into this. so you need to make the instance of that List type, so do something like this

```
List<KeyValuePair<Guid, string>> list =  new List<KeyValuePair<Guid, string>>();
```

and now trying to add item into this `list`

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `List` variable to something other than `null`, like this:

```
List<KeyValuePair<Guid, string>> List = new List<KeyValuePair<Guid, string>>();
```

Otherwise, this line will trigger the exception:

```
 List.Add(new KeyValuePair<Guid, string>(p.ProjectId, p.ProjectName));
 // ^
 // |
 // +------ List variable is null
```

Note that the `if (projects != null)` condition is unnecessary: `ToList()` could return an empty list, but it never returns `null`. In addition, you do not need to use `== true` with Boolean variables, unless they are nullable.

Finally, the `foreach` loop can be folded with LINQ's `Select`, like this:

```
try {
    using (LiveLeaseEntities db = LiveLeaseHelper.GetDbLiveLeaseEntities()) {
        return db.t_Project
            .Where(p => p.IsActive)
            .Select(p => new KeyValuePair<Guid, string>(p.ProjectId, p.ProjectName))
            .ToList();
     }
} catch {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the variable `List` (by the way, **use absolutely another name**)

```
List<KeyValuePair<Guid, string>> List = null;
```

but never initialized

```
List<KeyValuePair<Guid, string>> List = new List<KeyValuePair<Guid, string>>();
```

Of course when you try to use this variable you get the NullReferenceException

```
List.Add(.....) <- NullReferenceException without the initialization
```